# SSIS transferring data from Excel could not retrieve table information

Tags: ssis

I have been trying since yesterday and beating my head against a wall trying to obtain data from an excel provider.

I have literally tried everything. I double checked so as to make sure whether my version of excel is 32 bit, it is 32 bit. I even installed the x64 version of Microsoft database engine it still did not change the slightest thing. I have changed Run64BitRuntime to false and delay validation to true. Nothing has changed in the slightest. I have tried using the work book from 2003-2007 and 2007+ to save and then use it still has not changed a single thing. It feels like i am banging my head against the wall after watching countless youtube videos tons of online articles and it still does not seem to work. I would really appreciate some help. The version of Visual Studio i am using is 2019.

SSIS transferring data from Excel could not retrieve table information is the error message i always get after tons of tries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried all Excel versions in the Excel Connection Manager? Also, close the Excel workbook while working on the SSIS package.

[image]

Comment: Sadly i have tried this out as well but it seems to be of no help.

Comment: I suggest you to re-install SSDT and then ensure the Run64BitRuntime Project Property is set to False (which you have followed earlier). Be sure to close all excel files while working on SSIS.

Comment: It worked out after all when i used a different Excel version. Thanks for your help